# How can I get an NPAPI plugin to read an "src" tag

Tags: c++, c, npapi

i'm a little stuck on getting a plugin to work. I need it to take a "src" parameter but I can't seem to make it do this.

So i've basically got the npsimple basic plugin.

It's probably something really silly i'm missing
Joe

Comment: Just as an aside... if you use 'data' instead of 'src' the browser will automatically create a stream for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get `src` as one of the parameters that are passed to [`NPP_New()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NPP_New):

```
NPError NPP_New
          (NPMIMEType    pluginType,
           NPP instance, uint16 mode,
           int16 argc,   char *argn[],
           char *argv[], NPSavedData *saved)
{
    char* srcValue = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<argc; ++i) 
    {
        if(strcmp("src", argn[i]) == 0) {
            srcValue = argv[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    /* ... */
}
```